# Оптимальный формат для хранения больших текстовых данных

Tags: python, json, xml, text, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой формат выбрать для хранения текстовых данных большого объема. 
Он должен соответствовать следующим критериям (хотя бы 3 из 5). Критерии идут в порядке приоритета:

- Удобное представление структуры данных (вложенность данных может быть произвольной глубины)
- Поддержка библиотеками python (конвертирование, парсинг)
- Быстрый и маленький (парсинг, загрузка в БД)
- Удобное распространение (скачивание, отправка по сети)
- Человекочитаемый вид (возможность чтение и редактирования напрямую человеком)

Рассматриваю форматы - CSV, XML, JSON. Буду благодарен советам по выбору из указанных форматов или вашим предложениям.

---

UPD. Немного уточнений к вопросу. Почему озаботился выбором формата?

Собрал большой объем данных для своего проекта (инженерные и научные данные).

Встала задача по их структурированию и хранению, вдруг кому-то пригодится информация, а я смогу ему передать. Следовательно, человекоподобный вид будет весьма кстати.

Возможно, какое-то значение изменится, и чтобы не запускать парсинг по новой требуется править напрямую файл редактором

Кроме того, полученных данные нужно импортировать в базу данных, в моем случае PostgresQL, и любой человек, который принял мои текстовые данные, может сделать то же самое в любую удобную ему БД

Comment: В порядке убывания предпочтения: json, xml, csv. У json меньше накладные расходы (компактнее), xml уже несколько лет подряд теряет популярность среди программистов. Оба формата можно валидировать. Поддержка уже проникает и в СУБД, от майкрософт по крайней мере.

Comment: csv совсем плох?

Comment: Проще, чем CSV с экранированием разделителей вы не найдёте. И редактировать его можно любым табличным редактором. А вопрос подлежит закрытию, т. к. из серии "посоветуйте мне <...>".

Comment: Как улучшить? Понимаю, что вопрос максимально общий, но адекватных ответов на стаке и сравнений форматов не нашел

Comment: ну, наверное, поддержка языками, поддержка схемы. Ожидания по памяти,с другой стороны, ну, может его и нельзя улучшить, но и удалять не следует.

Comment: @D-side на самом деле, подумал, и сейчас против закрытия, учитывая вредоносный ответ АК, явно не все понимают разницу в форматах. Тем более, дубликатов вопроса нет.

Comment: добавил уточнения к вопросу, чтобы прояснить, почему я озаботился поиском формата

Comment: Возможно стоит сразу структурировать в базе данных (реляционная, колоночная, графовая, документоориентированная ..., под задачу), с нужными связями, быстрой выборкой. Сомнительно что кто-то быстро сможет разобраться если связи не явно описаны даже в человекочитаемом формате. sql дамп тоже легко редактировать редактором. Из базы экспорт в csv, json легче чем наоборот.

Comment: То есть при парсинге сразу отправлять данные в БД, минуя промежуточные форматы?

Comment: https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets давай проще. Посмотри в каком формате они выдают данные для всех. Используй этот формат

Comment: @while1pass обычно получается так, берем плоскую таблицу, обычно excel, забиваем данные. После необходимо дополнить их, используем фильтр. Другие начинают нам помогать, но за тем что добавляется нужно следить, возникают проблемы с названием одного и того же. При совместной работе лучше предоставлять доступ к базе данных, чем собирать файлы и пытаться найти соответствия. Отталкивайтесь от задач, но начинайте с малого.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

итак, включаем голову:

одни и те же данные в csv, json:

csv: (вместо \t будет |)

```
country|city
US|New York
Russia|Moscow
```

json:

```
{[{"country":"US", "city":"New York"},{"country":"Russia", "city":"Moscow"}]}
```

сравните длину строчек.  У кого больше? у JSON.

JSON/XML удобны тем, что структурированы, могут описать схему данных.
CSV удобен тем, что очень компактен, минимальные расходы на парсинг.

- любой не бинарный формат человек может редактировать очень легко. некоторые бинарные форматы достаточно просты, чтобы их можно было редактировать в hex-редакторе, особенно, если вы привыкли.
- официально JSON поддерживает ТОЛЬКО  UTF-8. CSV может быть в любой кодировке.
- если у вас очень сложные данные, сильно связанные, данные, которые трудно представить в виде одной-двух таблиц, возможно, вам следует присмотреться к json/xml.

Если вы просто заливаете тексты в бд, экспортируете их,  csv вполне справится.

В целом-то это вопрос выбора временного формата - формата для экспорта или трансляции по сети, во внешние системы (никто не хранит данные в csv/json/xml в качестве основного онлайн-хранилища)

Если у вас очень большие прямо тексты, храните их в текстовых файлах и в базе данных, а в csv/json/xml давайте ссылки на файлы. Структура усложняется, но и редактировать человеку проще.

Зато разница между форматами нивелируется. Короче, как всегда, все зависит от архитектуры и задач.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. как понимаю, большая вложенность вредит csv,  ухудшает его понимание человеком

Comment: у csv не "большая вложенность", у него просто все поля подряд идут, двумерные данные табличного вида. Каждую строку можно как угодно интерпретировать, с другой стороны в JSON/XML всегда прописано, что и где лежит, но и парсить их дороже и тяжелее

Comment: добавил уточнения к вопросу, чтобы прояснить, почему я озаботился поиском формата. да, основной критерий, как вы заметили, это распространение по сети, чтобы любой человек мог воспользоваться данными в своих целях. структура обладает большой вложенностью (3-5 кратной), и, возможно, будет усложнятся, поэтому для наглядности, наверно JSON/XML будет лучше

Comment: тогда csv, все sql-бд могут импортировать csv.

Comment: а что за данные? надеюсь не какие-нибудь "арийские веды в контексте белого православия" (просто интересно)

Comment: нееет. инженерные и научные данные (физхим свойства, данные структур, координаты, атомные параметры), там винегрет, который пытаюсь упорядочить